# Excluding Observations that Include a Specific Value

Tags: r

I would like to exclude observations that include specific values.
That is, the observations in my columns look like this: 501.512.518.
These represent three different individuals per observation.
Now I want to exclude all observations that include e.g. the individual 512

Is there a way to create sub-samples that can exclude observations which include the value 512 but do not equal or start with the value 512?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question lacks some details, still I hope this could help. I would used the *grepl* function.
In order to remove all rows in the dataset that (one of its) columns (denoted as col) contain (but don't start with) 512, do:

```
newDF <- oldDT[!grepl('.512', oldDF$col), ]
```

*grepl('.512', oldDF$col)* will return a logical vector with **TRUE** every-time the column "col" has the pattern ".512" in it.
The *!* infront of it will negate it and thus remove those rows.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Works like a charm Tal, Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note. If you wish to use the faster dplyr package, you could do so using the notation described by @steveb. If you need an example let me know.

Comment: You probably want '\\.512' since the dot will match anything on its own, so the original will match 0512 or 3512.  You can make this more robust by making it match the end of a line or non digit after the 512 (so that it does not match 5128) with something like '\\.512([^0-9]|$)'.  Of course this is overkill if all ID numbers are exactly 3 digits (in which case you could speed it up a little using the `fixed` argument to `grepl`).

Comment: Dear John, please take @Snow comment seriously and recheck your results. Indeed using the dot (".") without escaping it might have side effects. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had a more specific example but making some assumptions, and using `dplyr` you could do something like the following:

```
exclusion_values <- c(501, 512, 518)
new_df <- old_df %>% filter(! col_of_interest %in% exclusion_values)
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provide by @steveb is great, but you may want a base R alternative:

Example with mtcars dataset

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 50),
                 Number = sample(500:600, 200, replace = T))
```

to_drop <- c(512)

```
df <- df[!(df$Number %in% to_drop),]

 > df
    Group Number
1       A    518
2       B    536
3       C    518
4       D    505
5       A    544
6       B    511
7       C    507
```